# Filebeat is not sending data to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, snort

I’m trying to send alerts from Snort IDS to Elasticsearch, therefore I'm using 3 technologies:

- Elasticsearch- https://pastebin.com/uCNMaZFJ
- Logstash- https://pastebin.com/zgnbbw9K
- Filebeat- https://pastebin.com/45rC3rW5

My filebeat configuration file has this code inside:

```
input {
beats {
    port => 5044
}
```

}
filter {

```
if [type] == "snort" {

    # parse the message into individual fields
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "(?<ts>.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<host>.*?)\s.*?\s\[(?<generator_id>.*?)::(?<signature_id>.*?):.*?\]\s(?<signature>.*?)\s\[Classification:\s(?<classification>.*?)\]\s\[Priority:\s(?<priority>.*?)\].*?{(?<protocol>.*?)\}\s(?<source_ip>.*?):(?<source_port>.*?)\s-\>\s(?<destination_ip>.*?):(?<destination_port>.*)" }
    }

    # remove the original message if parsing was successful
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
        }
    }

    # parse the timestamp and save in a new datetime field
    if [ts] {
        date {
            match => [ "ts", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
            target => "sys_timestamp"
        }

        # remove the original timestamp if date parsing was successful
        if !("_dateparsefailure" in [tags]) {
            mutate {
                remove_field => [ "ts" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
output {

```
# save events to Elasticsearch with the uuid as the document id
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
manage_template => false
    index => "teste-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
}
```

}

I am expecting to see snort's alert logs when I check "http://localhost:9200/ola-*/_search?pretty", however the alerts are not retrieved. I’m struggling to fix this problem...I don't have any idea what is the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your stack? Your filebeat configuration file has both `filebeat.prospectors` and `filebeat.inputs`, since version 6.3 you should use `filebeat.inputs` instead of `filebeat.prospectors`.

Also the `document_type` configuration was removed since version 6.0, your message probably does not have a field called `type` with a value of `snort`, which is your main filter in the logstash pipeline. It's better to filter your messages using tags.

Use this in your `filebeat.yml` instead.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/snort/*.log
  tags: ["snort"]
```

And change your logstash filter, just use `if "snort" in [tags]` instead of `if [type] == "snort"`

Your output is sending any message that you receives to an index called `teste-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}`, why are you running a search against an index called `ola-*`? You should run a search against the `teste-*` index.

I recommend that you run your pipeline with the `stdout` output to see what is happening.

Just put this on your pipeline to see if you are getting any message and how are those messages.

```
output {
  stdout { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help! You have reason... I also think I can not use Unified2 file format directly in Filebeat... I have to think in way to overcome this problem.